# Less than 200 loc per class really practicable?

Tags: coding-style

I've had more than one lecture where we were told that classes shouldn't be bigger than about 200 lines of code.

However, I have had many projects with classes which had up to 500 or sometimes even more lines of code. Often, these classes seemed making sense just like they were, as all the functionality in those classes seemed to belong together.

My question is if it really makes sense (in most cases, there are always exceptions) to try to aim for smaller classes or is this just a wishful thinking in software developing which isn't always practicable (or even reasonable) in big projects?

Comment: LOC depends on coding style.  What language are you using?  (my guess is Java?)  There is no right answer to this, so the question will probably be closed as not productive.  However as a freebie, I will point to you Martin Fowler's classic work on Refactoring  http://books.google.com/books/about/Refactoring.html?id=1MsETFPD3I0C Using these techniques and "good" class design, typically your class implementation will be small.  Of course there will always be a few "heavy lifters" that make the most sense to have all the private methods implemented in the same class as the public method.

Comment: 200 loc is based on java / c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the source code of firefox and chromium with `cloc`, I get the following results:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project   Language    files       blank     comment        code    loc/file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
firefox   C++          5987      417603      318973     2156414         360
chromium  C++          3381      140033      128591      737553         218
```

I used the source codes of firefox 20.0 and chromium 4.0.249.0. 
In each project there were a lot of programming languages, I ignored all but the C++ part.

I see that the average lines of code count per file is over 200 for both projects. 
This means that a lot of files probably have much more as 200 loc, as there are surely also a lot of small files (and header and source files are even counted separately).

I am absolutely aware that my researches aren't really good ones to base my claim on, but after also doing some checks on different source files separately, I found that there are quite some files which have a lot more than 200 loc.

To answer my own question, I'd say that although one should always try to have small classes, there often are situations where splitting classes into smaller ones just to reduce the loc per class makes the project rather more complicated than the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on implementation and domain. If you can, you should always try to refactor your code and organize it into its most simple layout. Boil out the interfaces, implement using patterns like [Chesire Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) or [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Sometimes you need to have a lot of code in a single class, but it's a good 'rule of thumb' that if it looks like too much code, at least spend *some time* thinking about if it could be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of each class as a real life object representation. So, if the object is complex, the class will have more code. And less complex (small objects) will have less code.

You can try to split objects into individual components or take out common stuff to a parent class. But, there is always a limit to this.

Answer (score 0):

Single methods with a large amount of code in should be reduced in order to improve readability and understanding, but I would tend to say that as long as the code contained within the class itself is appropriate, then it should be fine to be included.